# Make computed Vue properties dependent on current time?

Tags: vue.js, time, computed-properties

I have a collection of `Events`. These will render in lists according to their status - upcoming/live/previous. Thus the rendering is dependent on the current time. How can I make the computed properties to update/recompute as time goes by?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Upcoming events</h2>
        <p v-bind:key="event.name" v-for="event in upcomingEvents">{{ event.name }}</p>

        <h2>Live events</h2>
        <p v-bind:key="event.name" v-for="event in liveEvents">{{ event.name }}</p>

        <h2>Previous events</h2>
        <p v-bind:key="event.name" v-for="event in previousEvents">{{ event.name }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Event from '../Event.js'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                events: []
            }
        },

        computed: {
            upcomingEvents() {
                return this.events.filter(event => event.isUpcoming())
            },

            liveEvents() {
                return this.events.filter(event => event.isLive())
            },

            previousEvents() {
                return this.events.filter(event => event.isPrevious())
            },
        },

        mounted() {
            // this.events are populated here 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can declare a time-dependent data variable and use `setInterval()` to update it:

```js
data() {
    return {
        events: [],
        now: Date.now()
    }
},
created() {
    var self = this
    setInterval(function () {
         self.now = Date.now()
    }, 1000)
},
computed: {
    upcomingEvents() {
        return this.events.filter(event => event.isUpcoming(this.now))
    },
    liveEvents() {
        return this.events.filter(event => event.isLive(this.now))
    },
    previousEvents() {
        return this.events.filter(event => event.isPrevious(this.now))
    }
}
```

Note that you need to use `now` in computed properties to make them update.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! Are computed props a good design pattern for this or would you do it better another way?

Comment: @Anders you should probably clearInterval in your beforeDestroy. +1

Answer (score 2):

You could create a time variable that you update every second then use this variable in your computed properties.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    time: ''
  },
  computed: {
    computedValue: function(){
        return this.time;
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
    var app = this;
    setInterval(function(){
      app.time = parseInt(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        }, 1000);
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ecwnvudz/

Answer (score 1):

One possibility for your case is [$forceUpdate()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate). However, it should be note that it will work specifically for your case because you're *NOT* using child components.

If you were to use child components, you would then need to use `slots` within the parent component and insert the children within their respective slots.

So, for example, you could do:

```
created() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.$forceUpdate()
    }, 5000)
}
```

Which will cause the entire component to re-render. This may or may not be the desirable interaction you're looking for.